# How to get bradmartin/nativescript-videoplayer element reference in my component using @viewChild?

Tags: typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

[Reference to the third party player on github.](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-videoplayer)

### Question:

How do I get the element reference of the third party nativescript-videoplayer in my component using viewChild?

**Error:**

My code compiles but crashes when I attempt to access the method play via this.videoPlayer.play()

> TypeError: this.videoPlayer.play is not a function. (In
>   'this.videoPlayer.play()', 'this.videoPlayer.play'
>   is undefined)

### Code:

**player.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

import {registerElement} from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
registerElement("VideoPlayer", () => require("nativescript-videoplayer").Video);

@Component({
    selector: "Player",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./player.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./player.component.css"]
})
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit{

    @ViewChild("video_player") videoPlayer: Video;

    public src: string = "<YOUR VIDEO URL HERE>"

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.videoPlayer.play();
    }
}
```

**player.component.html**

```
        <VideoPlayer
                #video_player
                [src]="src"
                height="300"></VideoPlayer>
```

[github issue reference #77](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-videoplayer/issues/77)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After checking the properties of `this.videoPlayer` via:

```
for(let prop in this.videoPlayer){
  if(this.videoPlayer.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
    console.dir(prop);
  }
}
```

I noticed that it only had one property "nativeElement". To be able to use it, I had to change the `viewChild` type from "`Video`" to "`ElementRef`" which let me access `nativeElement` and then allowed me to access all the API's defined on the documentation.

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

import {registerElement} from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
registerElement("VideoPlayer", () => require("nativescript-videoplayer").Video);

@Component({
    selector: "Player",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./player.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./player.component.css"]
})
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit{

    @ViewChild("video_player") videoPlayer: ElementRef;

    public src: string = "<YOUR VIDEO URL HERE>"

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.

I have a question, I was trying to change the source using string like you have here `src`. I was downloading the url from firebase and applying it to string but it didn't work. Although using hard-coded url was working fine.

By using viewchild, `this.videoPlayer.src = newSource` works fine.

I am curious what is wrong by changing the src directly?

Comment: Thank u for the rply. I tried using ViewChild and it worked.